# C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/param.h' error message while installing python jenkins package

Tags: python, jenkins, installation, package

I am installing Python Jenkins package on Windows 7 x64 bit PC.

I got following error:

> 'C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sys/param.h''. Python version
>   2.7.12.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

A very similar question was asked for Python in Linux and the solution there actually worked for me in Windows as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51306963/13082985  That is, if you were trying:

`pip install jenkins`

install this package instead:

`pip install python-jenkins`

Answer (score 0):

"sys/param.h" is known from unix/linux environments only.
I am not that sure but it might be further available with GNU C as well.

I have to assume something in your configuration or setup went horribly wrong.
As this question is rather specific to a certain project you might have more luck finding the answer if asking this directly at their project support channels.