# jenkins python module import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-module

I have installed jenkins module in the VM but still not able import the module and use.

Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 17 2014, 18:11:42)
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

```
import jenkins
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/jenkins.py", line 9, in <module>
lookup3 = cdll.LoadLibrary(os.path.join(get_python_lib(), "lookup3.so"))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 438, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 360, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lookup3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like it's missing some dependencies. Did you receive any errors during the jenkins installation.

Answer (score 17):

Have you installed jenkins by this command?

```
pip install jenkins
```

if yes you should try to install it with

```
pip install python-jenkins
```

Ref: [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-ci/+bug/1115573)

Answer (score 2):

This is already answered by `Daniel Salinas (imsplitbit)` on `lunchpad` at 
[bug in jenkins lib](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-ci/+bug/1115573)

> > Close this bug, it appears pip was installing jenkins 1.0.2 not python-jenkins 0.2 which is actually used. These two modules use the same module namespace so it may be valuable to change that some how or even just add python-jenkins to the pip-requires so that this isn't an issue to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I just met it. That's how it was solved

```
$ pip uninstall jenkins
Uninstalling jenkins-1.0.2:
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/__pycache__/jenkins.cpython-36.pyc
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jenkins-1.0.2-py3.6.egg-info
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/jenkins.py
  /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/lookup3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Proceed (y/n)?
```

here is a file: lookup3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so, soft connection to the corresponding position is OK

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/lookup3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lookup3.so
```